# Completion of the square

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Prove that for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$

$2^r + 3^r + 6^r - 4^r - 9^r \leq 1$

I have stared at it for quite sometime.. My prof suggested to use the completion of the square.

Answer (score 3):

Further hint: if $x = 2^r$ and $y = 3^r$, the left side is $x + y + x y - x^2 - y^2$

Comment: I have been trying to complete the square but I am getting frustrated. Also, how would you say it is $\leq 1$.
Could I say that it would be $\leq 1$ because the $-4^r and -9^r$ are negative, and they are the leading terms?.

Comment: What do you get when you complete the square, let's say with respect to $x$?  The difference, right side - left side, can be written as a sum of two squares.