# Prove that for all real numbers x, the inequality $2^x$ + $3^x$ - $4^x$ + $6^x$ -$9^x$ < 1 holds

Tags: inequality

Prove that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the inequality $2^x + 3^x - 4^x + 6^x - 9^x < 1$ holds.

Firstly, I rewrote the inequality as: $2^x + 3^x - (2^x)^2 + (2^x \cdot 3^x) - (3^x)^2 < 1$ and then tried to analyze a function for $x > 1$ and $x < 0$. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: have you tried substitution of $u = 2^x$ and $v = 3^x$?

Comment: Inequality is false for x=0.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is an equality if and only if $x$=$0$

Comment: Then the sign $\le$ seems more convenient.

Comment: Another one here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563209/completion-of-the-square.

Comment: this one also appears in Putnam and Beyond